# Extract unread emails (in Plain Text) and store in a Google Doc

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

**Problem:** Daily we get a dozen of mails. We need to print all of them in regular basis. Is it possible for a Google Apps Script to read only the unread mails and to store them in a Google Doc? No HTML nothing, I just need the plain text in the following format.

> **​From:** S. Banerjee  **Date:** 3 January
>   2017 at 02:40 **Subject:** Re: Happy New Year To: "Br. Sayan"
>
> ...... ...... Message ..... ......

I was searching for a solution, but only managed to get something like the following [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/20042-save-gmail-as-google-doc). Now we need to get the `msgID`s of the unread mail pass them on to the function. Rest of the formatting can be solved later on piecemeal basis I think.

```
function saveGmail(msgID) {

  // Based on Drive Scoop
  // Available at https://github.com/google/gfw-deployments

  var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(msgID);

  // Grab the message's headers.
  var from = message.getFrom();
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  var to = message.getTo();
  var cc = message.getCc();
  var date = message.getDate();
  var body = message.getBody();

  // Begin creating a doc.
  var document = DocumentApp.create(subject);  
  var document_title = document.appendParagraph(subject);  
  document_title.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);

  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = (DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  document_title.setAttributes(style);

  var headers_heading = (document.appendParagraph("Gmail Message Headers"));
  headers_heading.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);

  AddGmailHeaderToDoc(document, "From", from);
  AddGmailHeaderToDoc(document, "To", to);
  AddGmailHeaderToDoc(document, "Cc", cc);
  AddGmailHeaderToDoc(document, "Date", date);
  AddGmailHeaderToDoc(document, "Subject", subject);

  var body_heading = (
    document.appendParagraph("Body (without Markup)"));
  body_heading.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);

  var sanitized_body = body.replace(/<\/div>/, "\r\r");
  sanitized_body = sanitized_body.replace(/<br.*?>/g, "\r");
  sanitized_body = sanitized_body.replace(/<\/p>/g, "\r\r");
  sanitized_body = sanitized_body.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
  sanitized_body = sanitized_body.replace(/'/g, "'");
  sanitized_body = sanitized_body.replace(/"/g, '"');
  sanitized_body = sanitized_body.replace(/&/g, "&");
  sanitized_body = sanitized_body.replace(/\r\r\r/g, "\r\r");

  var paragraph = document.appendParagraph(sanitized_body);

  document.saveAndClose();

  return document.getUrl();

}

function AddGmailHeaderToDoc(document, header_name, header_value) {
  if (header_value === "") return;
  var paragraph = document.appendParagraph("");
  paragraph.setIndentStart(72.0);
  paragraph.setIndentFirstLine(36.0);
  paragraph.setSpacingBefore(0.0);
  paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0.0);    
  var name = paragraph.appendText(header_name + ": ");
  name.setBold(false);
  var value = paragraph.appendText(header_value);
  value.setBold(true);
}
```

Your help will be very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

An easier way might be to use 'is:unread' search

```
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:unread');
  var messages = threads[0].getMessages(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(messages[i].getId());
  }
```

This will log the Id's but you can return them as well.  Also note that threads and messages are different.  The above will get the first unread thread and all the messages in this thread (even if the messages are read).

Comment: It's throwing up an error : `TypeError: Cannot find function getMessages in object `. `GmailApp.search('is:unread');`is working because `Logger.log` shows the number of unread messages, when checked with : `Logger.log("Found " + threads.length + " messages.");`

Comment: Sorry the [0] was in wrong spot, updated answer for you.